# Extracting trendline slope with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, trendline

I'm currently making a macro to extract raw data from multiple csvs, print it in different sheets, trim extraneous data, plot data from each sheet on a single graph with individual trendlines, and report some information for said trendlines and data. I've had success with everything except extracting the trendline slopes. I want to report the slope average of all the trendlines and I've written the code below to do this action:

```
For j = 1 To UBound(SelectedSheets)
    TLEq = CompositeChartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection(j).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text
    ReDim Preserve ModulusArr(j)
    ModulusArr(j) = CDbl(Mid(TLEq, 4, Len(TLEq) - 4))
Next j
```

SelectedSheets is an array  filled with the sheets the user selects to be analyzed from a multi-select userform listbox. TLEq is a string to temporarily hold the full text of the trendline equation (intercept set to 0 so simple y = mx equation). The CDbl(Mid()) is used to trim TLEq to just the slope and convert to a Double. In lines above these (not included), the series are added, trendlines inserted, and DisplayEquation is called for each trendline. There has been no issues with graphing, trendlines showing up, or trendline equations displaying.

**The issue begins in line 2 where TLEq is inconsistently left blank during the loop; some iterations all the trendline equation are extracted, sometimes only some are, and other times no equations are extracted.. I have yet to find any pattern. Then, anytime TLEq is empty, line 4 errors because it cannot carry out the CDbl(Mid()) an empty TLEq. Any ideas?**

Comment: what is `CompositeChartObject`?

Comment: @ArcherBird a chart object that contains an xlXYScatterSmooth chart displaying the data series from each selected sheet.